# How to customize org-mode html output to replace emojis?

Tags: org-mode, htmlize.el

I have added emojis to my `org-mode` document like this:

> bla bla :turtle: bla yadda

When looking at it through the GitHub viewer, they get substituted to the corresponding unicode character entities.

Which hooks I have to pull to get the same effect in org-mode html (esp. ox-reveal) export?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [company-emoji](https://github.com/dunn/company-emoji) package. Download it and then put the following in your init file:

```
(require 'company-emoji)
(add-to-list 'company-backends 'company-emoji)
```

It works for me with org-html-export-to-html. Don't know about ox-reveal though but would assume it will display the emojis as well.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that there is a customizable variable for this purpose:

```
org-export-html-protect-char-alist is a variable defined in `org-html.el'.
Its value is (("&" . "&amp;") ("<" . "&lt;") (">" . "&gt;"))

Documentation:
Alist of characters to be converted by `org-html-protect'.

You can customize this variable.

This variable was introduced, or its default value was changed, in
version 24.1 of Emacs.
```

So for now (not being a hard-core Emacs Lisp user) I just put this in my `.emacs`:

```
(defcustom org-export-html-protect-char-alist
  '(("&" . "&amp;")
    ("<" . "&lt;")
    (">" . "&gt;")
    (":turtle:" . "&#x1f422;")
    (":dash:" . "&#x1f4a8;")
    (":-)" . "&#x1f60a;")
    (":-(" . "&#x1f61e;"))
  "Alist of characters to be converted by `org-html-protect'."
  :group 'org-export-html
  :version "24.1"
  :type '(repeat (cons (string :tag "Character")
           (string :tag "HTML equivalent"))))
```

This works nicely, but maybe there is a better way to just append to the customizable variable?